# CCRC Synchronization with Remote copy

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I am using CCRC 7.1.2 in our project.Is there any option to synchronize local copy with remote copy so that we can update only the modified files?

**Refresh->Update from repository** option is giving entire folder contents that we are updating but i need only the modified files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Refresh->Update from Repository" should be available at the file level
(see "[Updating a resource in a ClearCase view](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.ccrc.help.doc/topics/t_ccview_update_resource.htm)", which should apply also to CCRC , not just the ClearCase Explorer with a classic ClearCase installation)

That means you can select a modified file and ask for the latest version of that file, you don't have to update the all folder or the all view.

Comment: if there is 10 files in a folder which i checked out today after that somebody checked in 5 extra files in the same folder.can i get that 5 files alone without updating existing files.This functionality is there in SVN, will it be applicable here also ?

Comment: @VineethBhaskaran any regular update should not change your file if they are currently modified (here checked out)